# How to add a lookup result to projected value in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a `$lookup` result saved as `username` and I want to add that to a projected result called `approval`. I thought I might be able to add it like this: `'approval.username' : '$username'`, however that didn't work.

How do I add the `username` result to the projected results? (Also `username` returns an array of other data, how do I specify `firstname` and `lastname` keys only.)

```
$project: {
            address: 1,
            approval: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$approval", 0],
                },
            }
```

Note that I want to maintain all the results projected in `approval`.

At the moment the output is:

```
{
address: { 'addresshere' },
approval: { recordToApprove : "1010", createDT : "2020-07 18T14:29:54+01:00"}
}
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
{
address: { 'addresshere' },
approval: { recordToApprove : "1010", createDT : "2020-07 18T14:29:54+01:00", username: {firstname: 'First', lastname: 'Last' }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with the `$mergeObjects` operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      address: 1,
      user_details: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$approval", 0]
          },
          {
            username: { $arrayElemAt: ["$username", 0] }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yueIpiTFN4d) | [Alternative $let](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BUJuOCm4zAl)

Comment: Thanks Valijon! One question, how do I maintain the original data in the approval array?

Comment: @tbowden If you change to this: `in: "$$approval"` will return entire `approval[0]` value

Comment: Ah ok, I see. So how do I put it together so I can see username in the approval array? (Sorry I should have made this more clear)

Comment: @tbowden Update your question with expected result please

Comment: @tbowden Check again please. Woul be nice if you post `username` value